# Lenovo T450S laptop docking station issue

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, docking-station

I am having difficulty utilizing a docking station with my Lenovo T450s laptop. I purchased the laptop in 2016 and it is running Windows 10. At the time of purchase I also bought a Lenovo docking station. At the suggestion of an IT person, I recently purchased a "Plugable USB 3.0" docking station.

The issue I am having now with both docking stations is that my second monitor does not get detected and only works when I connect directly to the laptop and it does not transfer the wired internet signal from the docking station to the laptop. The signal is fine when I connect directly to the laptop. All of the USB ports on the laptop are USB 3.0.

I was under the impression that I could plug the power for the laptop and one cable from the docking station and would be good to go. The printers connected through the docking stations work fine. I take my laptop home with me every day from work. Any suggestions to try?

Comment: Check for and install firmware updates to the dock and laptop.

Comment: If the docking station is a `ThinkPad USB 3.0 Docking Station`, then update the driver. See [ThinkPad USB 3.0 Docking Station troubleshooting](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht080927).